# LatLng to Bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've found severals things but still can't find the correct answer.
I get the position from my input (by using google maps autocomplete), so i finally get the long and lat.
I need to get the SWLat/Long and NELat/Long.
So i have tried to use the bounds so I have used it :

```
    var resultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(long, lat));


 latNEValue = resultBounds.getNorthEast().lat();
longNEValue = resultBounds.getNorthEast().lng();
latSWValue = resultBounds.getSouthWest().lat();
longSWValue = resultBounds.getSouthWest().lng();
```

My problem is that the values are equal two by two (latNE == lat == latSW and longNE == long = longSW.
I cannot find the right solution.
Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a google.maps.LatLngBounds object associated with the [placeResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult) (the `.viewport` of the [PlaceGeometry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceGeometry)).  Best to use that (if it exists, if it isn't known, it will be null).